# using bash function in zsh

Tags: bash, macos, zsh

I have a function that worked fine in `bash`

```
function cfwipe() {
    local space_guid=`cf space --guid  $1`
    cf t -s $1
    for a in `cf curl /v2/spaces/$space_guid/apps | jq -r .resources[].entity.name`; do cf delete -r -f $a; done
    for a in `cf curl /v2/spaces/$space_guid/service_instances | jq -r .resources[].entity.name`; do cf ds -f $a;done
    for a in `cf curl /v2/user_provided_service_instances?q=space_guid:$space_guid | jq -r .resources[].entity.name`; do cf ds -f $a;done
}
```

I copied the function to `.zshrc` file and added it to `autoload`

```
if type brew &>/dev/null; then
    FPATH=$(brew --prefix)/share/zsh-completions:$FPATH

    autoload -Uz compinit cfwipe
    compinit
fi
```

However when I try to run it - despite starting the execution it fails and repeats in console the same line

```
no matches found: .resources[].entity.name
...
```

What is the problem?
Even with spellcheck fixes it doesn't work

```
cfwipe() {
    space_guid=$(cf space --guid  "$1")
    cf t -s "$1"
    for a in $(cf curl /v2/spaces/"$space_guid"/apps | jq -r .resources[].entity.name); do cf delete -r -f "$a"; done
    for a in $(cf curl /v2/spaces/"$space_guid"/service_instances | jq -r .resources[].entity.name); do cf ds -f "$a";done
    for a in $(cf curl /v2/user_provided_service_instances?q=space_guid:"$space_guid" | jq -r .resources[].entity.name); do cf ds -f "$a";done
}
```

Comment: I see a lot of unquoted variables and stuff like that. Start by fixing the problems pointed out by https://www.shellcheck.net/ if that doesn't help, update the answer.

Comment: @Socowi but it worked with Iterm because I switched to zsh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't quote the `jq` filters. The `[]` in the filters makes both shells recognize the strings as patterns and attempt to apply pathname generation. By default, `bash` treats an unmatched pattern as literal text. `zsh`, on the other hand, treats an unmatched pattern as an error.

If you had a file named `.resources.entity.name` in the current directory, both shells would use that as the result of pathname generation, altering the string you meant to pass as an argument to `jq`.

If you don't want the shell to process a string, quote it.

```
... | jq -r '.resources[].entity.name'
```

Unfortunately, `shellcheck` cannot flag this as an error, because it doesn't know what an arbitrary command expects its arguments to be: maybe the unquoted pattern was intentional.

---

As an aside, either shell's default behavior can be changed. To make `bash` behave like `zsh`, use

```
shopt -s failglob
```

To make `zsh` behave like `bash`, use

```
setoption NO_NOMATCH
```

(I'm not sure why there is an option named `NOMATCH` enabled by default, rather than an option named `MATCH` that is disabled by default.)

Answer (score 0):

I set NO_NOMATCH, escape jq '.[]'. Doesn't work for me at all. Bash works fine.